# Django settings: How to access variables from the settings folder in an app

Tags: django, django-settings, django-apps

I have a Django project with the following structure:

```
--|src
  --project
  --|settings
     --__init__.py
     --production.py
     --local.py
  --|app1
```

In my app I import the settings (`from django.conf import settings`) and then as I was following a tutorial they said to do this `getattr(settings, VARIABLE)`. That doesn't work for me. Instead I can do this: `settings.VARIABLE`. What's the difference?

Oh and I ran `type(settings)` and it outputted `<class 'django.conf.LazySettings'>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in order to access variables in settings.py file, you can do like this:

for example, I define STATIC_ROOT variable in settings.py file like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static', 'static_root')
```

and I can access to this variable like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT
```

Comment: I don't understand how this is the accepted answer. You just confirmed what he said in the question, not explained why the difference!

Answer (score 6):

The difference is that for various reasons (see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#use-of-django-conf-settings) for details), the settings object is not loaded unless an object is referenced from it.

The `LazySettings` object is special and you have to access it with `settings.SOMETHING`.

The reason its called "Lazy" is because the entire object is not loaded and made available to you when you import it. This `LazySettings` object acts like a proxy to the actual settings object.

Comment: This answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

project DIR
--|app DIR
   --|settings.py <<< your variable API_KEY = '28234-jns-23-23n'

```
from app.settings import API_KEY
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question